# Web application to Mobile

Tags: android, javascript, html, ios, css

I have a vanilla JS web application. Super basic. Some HTML, some CSS, and some JS. The server side is written in Node.js. I want to now make the UI portion of the app built as an Android and IOS app for mobile. I have looked at the following products but am still not sure. I don't *think* there is a one-to-one solution, but maybe I am wrong. Basically I don't want to write my UI twice.. but maybe it is necessary. I am trying to avoid React/Vue/Angluar etc because, well, I hate them. All I need is HTML and vanilla JS.

So far I have looked in to

- PhoneGap
- ionic
- electron (obviously wrong, if it built for Mobile it would be perfect)
- jquery UI

I really don't want to re-write my web app in jQuery, or React, or Angular. I am *totally* fine doing this in a hacky way, as long as it works. But it really needs to support ES6 and all the type of events we are used to like drag events, click events, etc.

Comment: Broargh. Welcome in the future!

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://css-tricks.com/how-to-get-a-progressive-web-app-into-the-google-play-store/  I have never written an android app, nor really a PWA!